# What's the original name of Microsoft Azure Machine Learning?

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

In this talk https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2015/BRK3550 the speaker mentions that the Azure ML service originally had a different name.

My stack and google searches have shown no results so far.
Does anyone know it by chance?

Edit: The fragment i'm talking about starts at 56:00 and is a couple of seconds long.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a programming question. It's a product naming history query.

Comment: It isn't anything interesting, just a code name that we still use to label our preprod env

Comment: Just nice to know like SQL Server Yukon or Katmai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for **Project Passau**. Here's one of the references, in [Visual Studio Magazine](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/09/01/azure-machine-learning-studio.aspx) or another one [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mspowerutilities/2014/07/08/harnessing-the-power-of-big-data-with-cloud-predictive-analytics-introducing-azure-machine-learning/).

Comment: That's actually awesome that you found this! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The whole platform was named [Windows Azure](http://blogs.microsoft.com/blog/2010/02/01/windows-azure-general-availability/) before it was [changed in 04/2014](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/03/25/upcoming-name-change-for-windows-azure/) along with its services.

Comment: I'm actually talkin about the Azure Machine Learning product itself. The presenter talks about this at the 56:00 mark in the presentation.

Or do you think he does refer to windows azure vs microsoft azure?

Comment: From the video it's clear he's referring to an internal pre-release name. So you'd have to ask a developer. It's obviously nothing publicly disclosed.

Comment: True, guess we'll probably never know. Thanks for the effort!